# Connnecting ADO.net connection string via sqlserver(in docker mac)

Tags: sql-server, docker, ado.net, sql-server-2019

I manage to successfully create and connect to the database via azure_data_studio

docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=P@ssword1" -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

In ADO.net core I am supposed to provide a connection string.

I don't know how to create one.
connetionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=Databasename;
User ID=UserName;Password=Password"

// Would the string look like this. Is catalog the table name.
String connectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Northwind;" + "Integrated Security=true";

Comment: If you just created the container and haven't connected to it yet, it's not going to have a database called Northwind. I would just not specify an initial catalog, and try `127.0.0.1` instead of `(local)` or `ServerName`. You're also going to need to connect initially as `sa` and the password you provided on the command line, and you won't be able to use `Integrated Security`.

Comment: Since you don't specify a network parameter when starting the SQL container it will likely be in the Default Bridge network. If the .NET Core code is connecting from the host operating system try `Server=127.0.0.1,1433;` but if it's connecting from another container (in the Default Bridge network) try `Server=host.docker.internal,1433;` instead. For authentication you'll need to use SQL Logins with username and password unless you're joining the containers to a domain/AD that you're not showing in the question.